# Selectinput and Action buttons not working as expected just one plots in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

My intention is to plot graphs first from selection of Types objects and unit objects then faceted unit and type objects, The challenge I am facing is when I run the app, only one action button works and the rest even selections dont work.

I have data the has different unit and Type objects. I would like if I run the up FIRST plot is selection of unit and types then faceted plots from the two action button type and unit.

I have attached some data

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(DT)
library(feather)
library(reshape2)
library(pander)

suppressMessages(library(dplyr))

library(signal)

library(prospectr)

setwd("path")
#list.files()
#neos <- read.csv("Neospec processed with codes.csv")
#wrt<-write_feather(neos,"path")
#neos<- read_feather("path")
#neos[1:7,1:5]





ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Neospec Visualization"),
  sidebarLayout(


    sidebarPanel(

      #fileInput(inputId = "fls", "Upload Neodata", multiple = F, buttonLabel = "Load file", placeholder = "No file loaded", accept = NULL),

      uiOutput("unit"),

      uiOutput("Type"),

      uiOutput("FaceUnit"),

      tags$hr(),

      uiOutput("FaceType")

    ),



    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("table"),6),

      h3("Data table view"),
      #withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput("contents"),6),
      #dataTableOutput("tt"),
      h3("Raw Neospec signatures"),
      withSpinner(plotOutput("plts"),6)

    )

  )
  )
)




server <- function(input, output){

  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=150*1024^2)

  #upld.dt<- reactive({

    #inFile <- input$fls

    #if (is.null(inFile))

      #return(NULL)

    #all.spec<-read.csv(inFile$datapath)

    #all.spec
#})


  neos <- reactive({read_feather("path")})

  #########Ui to select Units and type#############################


  output$unit <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "unit", label = "Select Unit", choices = as.vector(unique(neos()$unit)), selected = NULL)

  })

  output$Type <- renderUI({

    selectInput(inputId = "Type", label = "Select Type", choices = as.vector(unique(neos()$Type)), selected = NULL)

  })

  output$FaceUnit <- renderUI({

    actionButton(inputId = "FaceUnit", label = " Unit", choices = as.vector(unique(neos()$FaceUnit)))

  })

  output$FaceType <- renderUI({

    actionButton(inputId = "FaceType", label = " Type", choices = as.vector(unique(neos()$FaceType)))

  })

  #########################Subset data by stds##########################

  sbst.unt<-reactive({
    neodt<-neos()
    unt.sbst <- neodt[(neodt$unit==input$unit & neodt$Type==input$Type),]
    unt.sbst
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({sbst.unt()})



  ###Plot by selection of Unit and Type ################################

  output$plts <- renderPlot({

    plt.dt <- sbst.unt()

    wavelength<-as.numeric(substr(colnames(plt.dt[,-c(1:3)]),2,19))

    colnames(plt.dt) <- c("SSN","unit","Type",wavelength)

    spec.m <- melt(plt.dt, id = c("SSN","unit","Type"))


    p <- ggplot(data =spec.m , aes(x = as.numeric(as.vector(variable)),y = value, group = SSN)) +

      geom_line(size = 0.1, col = "blue", alpha = 0.8) +

      ggtitle("Neospec raw spectrums ") +

      xlim(range(wavelength))+

      ylim(c(0,1)) +

      xlab("Wavelength (nm)") +

      ylab("Reflectance") + 
      #theme with white background
      theme_bw() +
      #eliminates background, gridlines, and chart border
      theme(
        plot.background = element_blank()
        ,panel.grid.major = element_blank()
        ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
      )
    p <- p + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

    p <- p + theme(legend.position = "none")

    p

  })

  ###Plot by Action button of Type ################################# 

  sbst.unt<-reactive({
    neodt <- neos()
    unt.sbst <- neodt[(neodt$unit==input$unit & neodt$Type==input$Type),]
    unt.sbst
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    sbst.unt()
  })

  # here you react off the FaceType button
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$FaceType,{
    req(input$FaceType)
    neos()
  })

  output$plts <- renderPlot({
    plt.dt2 <- plotdata()

    wavelength2 <- as.numeric(substr(colnames(plt.dt2[,-c(1:3)]),2,19))
    colnames(plt.dt2) <- c("SSN","unit","Type",wavelength2)
    spec.m2 <- melt(plt.dt2, id = c("SSN","unit","Type"))

    p2 <- ggplot(data = spec.m2 , aes(x = as.numeric(as.vector(variable)),y = value, group = SSN)) +
      geom_line(size = 0.1, col = "blue", alpha = 0.8) +
      ggtitle("Neospec raw spectrums ") +
      xlim(range(wavelength2))+
      ylim(c(0,1)) +
      xlab("Wavelength (nm)") +
      ylab("Reflectance") + 
      #theme with white background
      theme_bw() +

      #eliminates background, gridlines, and chart border
      theme(
        plot.background = element_blank(),panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
    p2 <- p2 + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    p2 <- p2 + theme(legend.position = "none")
    fac.typ <- p2 + facet_grid(.~Type, switch ='y', scales = "free")
    fac.typ
  })


  ###Plot by Action button of unit ##################################

  sbst.unt<-reactive({
    neodt <- neos()
    unt.sbst <- neodt[(neodt$unit==input$unit & neodt$Type==input$Type),]
    unt.sbst
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    sbst.unt()
  })

  # here you react off the FaceType button
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$Faceunit,{
    req(input$Faceunit)
    neos()
  })

  output$plts <- renderPlot({
    plt.dt2 <- plotdata()

    wavelength2 <- as.numeric(substr(colnames(plt.dt2[,-c(1:3)]),2,19))
    colnames(plt.dt2) <- c("SSN","unit","Type",wavelength2)
    spec.m2 <- melt(plt.dt2, id = c("SSN","unit","Type"))

    p2 <- ggplot(data = spec.m2 , aes(x = as.numeric(as.vector(variable)),y = value, group = SSN)) +

      geom_line(size = 0.1, col = "blue", alpha = 0.8) +

      ggtitle("Neospec raw spectrums ") +

      xlim(range(wavelength2))+

      ylim(c(0,1)) +

      xlab("Wavelength (nm)") +

      ylab("Reflectance") + 

      #theme with white background

      theme_bw() +

      #eliminates background, gridlines, and chart border
      theme(
        plot.background = element_blank(),panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

    p2 <- p2 + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

    p2 <- p2 + theme(legend.position = "none")

    fac.unit <- p2 + facet_grid(.~unit, switch ='y', scales = "free")

    fac.unit
  })  



}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

```
dput(
     SSN    unit    Type    X2600.000003874302  X2597.4609457191823 X2594.926835544204
     RResmicro1g3SI1    Unit1   soil    0.37285368  0.364537573 0.356995724
     RResmicro1g3SI1    Unit2   soil    0.295855514 0.292268904 0.289343551
     RResmicro1g3SI1    Unit3   soil    0.296041336 0.294366508 0.292749726
     RResmicro1mSGe2    Unit1   soil    0.387475087 0.38768638  0.387886013
     RResmicro1mSGe2    Unit2   soil    0.428004392 0.42284043  0.41852246
     RResmicro1mSGe2    Unit3   soil    0.422322559 0.419495941 0.416767303
      RresMicro1mtHj    Unit1   dung    0.458153765 0.456678695 0.455340966  
      RresMicro1mtHj    Unit2   dung    0.429987543 0.429523389 0.429238502  
  )
```

Comment: `actionButton` does not have `choices` as an argument. Add `session` to your server function.

Comment: Yes it does not have choices but it is supposed to facet plot for unit and Type,

Comment: Why kind of `dput` output is it?

Comment: @PoGibas I think OP misunderstand `dput` you can use `read.table` with the provided dataset.

Comment: my data initially was in csv but I converted it to feather format so that I can use it for for certain purpose, that is why i am, using read_feather